I wrote a take on the free will theory. It is different from other theories, but i want to know if what i wrote is acceptable or if it is blasphemy
I used ai to obviously extend on the topic but the core idea was thought out by me and the gravity idea. In no way am i declaring what i have wrote here is what i believe or that is is right in any case. I will only believe in this if it is accepted to be an appropriate explanation that is not blasphemous in any way nor does it undermine allah in any way. I just want to see if my answer to the free will question most people have is acceptable. Jazakallah.
Question:
Is it free will if God wrote everyone's faith down in the Preserved Tablet and knows what everyone is going to do, and what's the point if I'm going to follow what Allah has written down?
Here is my answer:
The concept of destiny in Islam, as written in the Preserved Tablet (Al-Lawh Al-Mahfuz), is indeed influenced by your free will. You have complete free will to make your own choices and decisions.
If someone is destined for hell due to their actions, it is not because Allah wrote it down to condemn them. Rather, Allah, in His infinite knowledge, knows exactly what choices you will make and records them. This foreknowledge does not cause your actions; it simply reflects what you will freely choose to do. The relationship between what is written in the Preserved Tablet and human actions is beyond full human comprehension. Allah writes down what you will do based on His knowledge of your free will, not because He wants to punish certain people arbitrarily.
Many people use the example of a teacher predicting which students will do well on a test and which ones will not. However, this example is not a good one because the teacher does not know exactly which questions each student will answer correctly or incorrectly. The teacher does not have full knowledge of the outcome. In contrast, Allah's knowledge is perfect and complete; He knows every detail of our actions and their outcomes.
To illustrate this with a real-life example: Imagine you know that if you drop an object, it will fall to the ground due to gravity. You can write down that the object will fall, but your writing does not cause the object to fall; gravity does. Similarly, free will exists independently. Just because Allah has written down your actions in the Preserved Tablet does not mean that His writing causes your actions. Instead, He writes what He knows you will do based on your free will. Allah's knowledge encompasses everything, and He is the Most Knowledgeable. He knows what is in every heart and what you do not know. Allah is the Most Just and Fair.
This understanding emphasizes that while Allah's knowledge is perfect and complete, it does not negate human free will. Your actions are your own, and you are responsible for them. Allah's recording of these actions is a reflection of His omniscience, not a determinant of your fate.
To further elaborate, consider the example of a computer program. A programmer writes a code that, when executed, will perform specific tasks. The programmer knows exactly what the program will do because they wrote the code. However, the program's actions are not caused by the programmer's knowledge but by the code itself. Similarly, Allah's knowledge of our actions does not cause them; it is our free will that leads to our actions, and Allah's knowledge simply encompasses what we will choose to do.
Another example is that of a mathematician solving an equation. The mathematician knows the exact outcome of the equation based on the mathematical principles involved. The outcome is not caused by the mathematician's knowledge but by the inherent properties of the equation. In the same way, Allah's knowledge of future events does not cause those events to happen; it is the natural course of actions and decisions made by individuals exercising their free will.
This answer does not undermine Allah's power and authority over all things. Rather, it highlights that He allows our free will to directly affect our destiny. Allah could determine our fate based on His will alone, as He has power over all things and the entire universe belongs to Him. However, He is the Most Just and the Most Fair. Therefore, He chooses to give us free will and allows our free will to directly influence our destiny. This balance between divine knowledge and human free will underscores Allah's justice and fairness.
In summary, the concept of destiny in Islam acknowledges both Allah's omniscience and human free will. Allah's knowledge of our actions and His recording of them in the Preserved Tablet do not negate our responsibility for our choices. We are accountable for our actions, and Allah's justice ensures that we are judged fairly based on what we freely choose to do. This understanding does not undermine Allah's power in any way, shape, or form. Instead, it affirms His ultimate authority and His just and fair nature in allowing human beings to exercise free will within His creation.
